# Julia - partially shared arrays with @parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I want to alter a shared array owned by only some of my processes:

```
julia> addprocs(4)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
2
3
4
5

julia> s = SharedArray(Int, (100,), pids=[2,3]);
julia>for i in procs() println(remotecall_fetch(localindexes, i, s)) end
1:0
1:50
51:100
1:0
1:0
```

This works, but I want to be able to parallelize the loop:

```
julia> for i=1:100 s[i] = i end
```

This results in processes 4 and 5 terminating with a segfault:

```
julia> @parallel for i=1:100 s[i] = i end
```

Question: Why does this terminate the processes rather than throw an exception or split the loop only among the processes that share the array?

I expected this to work instead, but it does not fill the entire array:

```
julia> @parallel for i in localindexes(s) s[i] = i end
```

Each process updates the part of the array that is local to it, and since the array is shared, changes made by one process should be visible to all processes.  Why is some of the array still unchanged?

Replacing `@parallel` with `@everywhere` gives the error that `s` is not defined on process 2.  How can a process which owns part of the array be unaware of it?

I am so confused.  What is the best way to parallelize this loop?

Comment: how big is this array (ideally bigger than 100 elements)? `SharedArray` objects are designed for really big data. also, for optimal performance, each `SharedArray` participating process should only work on its own subset of the array. if you want only a subset of processors to update the whole array, then you should first check that this is actually faster than having the master process do the work. the master process can see the whole array and has no parallel computing overhead, which can negate any potential speedups from parallelizing the update.

Comment: This may need someone of the extra generality of the newer (coming soon) parallel framework. For now you can write an implementation using `@spawnat`, but that wouldn't be very slick.

Comment: The array could potentially be huge enough to share across many hosts, like a high-resolution CFD simulation on a cluster for example, but I'm just trying to learn how the syntax is supposed to work right now.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the trick?

```
@sync begin
    for i in procs(s) # <-- note loop over process IDs of SharedArray s!
        @async @spawnat i setindex!(s, i, localindexes(s))
    end
end
```

You may run into issues if the master process is called here; in that case, you can try building your own function modeled on the [`pmap` example](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/parallel-computing/#scheduling).

Comment: the silence is deafening... :(